# Sniffing raw sockets (SOCK_RAW) without Administrator account in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

I am creating a simple sniffer using c++ under visual studio , and windows 10 x64 , but when I tried to run it. I got `Failed to create raw socket.` which is because admin rights , but I was reaching on internet . I could use something like `CAP_NET_ADMIN` , but it is linux based . is there a way to do under windows such as wireshark non-root users works?

```
//Initialise Winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup() failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Initialised");

    //Create a RAW Socket
    printf("\nCreating RAW Socket...");
    sniffer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sniffer == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed to create raw socket.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Created.");
```

Comment: You can elevate your process permissions. No need to run as another user,

Comment: [socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket): *"Otherwise, a value of INVALID_SOCKET is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling [WSAGetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror)."*

Comment: in a code level how can I ?

Comment: You cannot use a RAW socket without admin rights, that is clearly explained in MSDN's documentation. Wireshark gets around that by capturing packets directly at the networking level, not at the application level. See [How Wireshark Works](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChapterWorks.html)

Comment: is there another way to Sniffing raw sockets without using admin?

Comment: They have already told you, no. Besides, what's the meaning of sniffing other's information if you do not have admin privileges. If you *could* sniff without admin, that would be a big security flaw. Smells as If you were trying to implement malware.

Comment: not at all , but I want to check how it works.

Comment: @JESUSIVANBARRIOSRUBIO not with raw sockets, no. Use a capture library like libpcap, just as Wireshark does

Answer (score 1):

[Creating a Raw Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2#creating-a-raw-socket):

> Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying
>   transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a
>   security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group
>   can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting this with Wine, you need to allow the wineserver to use Ping.SendPrivileged:

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_RAW=ep /usr/bin/wine
sudo setcap CAP_NET_RAW=ep /usr/bin/wineserver
sudo setcap CAP_NET_RAW=ep YOUREXE.exe
```